# Optimal control via ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, parametric-functions, constraint

I'm wondering about the possibility of employing `ParametricNDSolve` to solve a class of constrained optimal control problems.

Here's an example: The system under consideration is $$\begin{pmatrix} \dot x_1(t)\\ \dot x_2(t)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x_2(t)\\ u(t) \end{pmatrix},$$ with initial condition $x_1(0) = -1/2$ and $x_2(0) = -1$. I have a specific form of the control trajectory given by $t\mapsto u(t) = c_1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi\mathcal D}} e^{-t^2/\mathcal D} + c_2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi\mathcal D}} e^{-(t-1)^2/\mathcal D}$, where $c_1, c_2$ are real-valued coefficients. The objective is to minimize $\int_0^2 u(t)^2 \,\mathrm{d}t$ subject to the preceding controlled differential equation while ensuring that, for instance, $x_1(t) \ge -1$ *for all time* $t\in[0, 2]$.

I begin with the initialization:

`tInit = 0; tFin = 2; paramD = 2;`

Then I build the solution:

```
solution = ParametricNDSolve[
   {x1'[t] == x2[t], 
    x2'[t] == 
     c1* E^(-t^2/paramD)/Sqrt[\[Pi] * paramD] + 
      c2*E^(-(t - 1)^2/paramD)/Sqrt[\[Pi] * paramD],
    x0'[t] == (c1* E^(-t^2/paramD)/Sqrt[\[Pi] * paramD] + 
        c2*E^(-(t - 1)^2/paramD)/Sqrt[\[Pi] * paramD])^2,
    (* initial conditions *)
    x1[tInit] == -1/2, x2[tInit] == -1, 
    x0[tInit] == 0}, 
   (* declare the states of the ode *)
   {x1, x2, x0}, 
   (* declare the time interval *)
   {t, tInit, tFin}, 
   (* declare the parameters *)
   {c1, c2}];
```

Here the variable $x_0$ keeps track of the objective function; the objective is to minimize $x_2(2)$, I think it should be possible to pass it on to `NMinimize`. For instance, extracting an optimal pair $(c_1^*, c_2^*)$ with linear constraints on $c_1, c_2$ can be done via:

```
NMinimize[{x0[c1, c2][tFin] /. solution, 
  1 <= c1 <= 4 && -5 <= c2 <= -1}, {c1, c2}]
```

However, this optimal pair $(c_1^*, c_2^*)$ solves the minimization problem **without** the pathwise constraint $x_1(t) \ge -1\;\forall t\in[0, 2]$ and with unnecessary constraints on $(c_1, c_2)$. Is there a mechanism to include the constraints on $x_1$ as mentioned above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, this problem can be solved by defining the function,

```
f[c1_?NumericQ, c2_?NumericQ] := 
    NMinValue[{x1[c1, c2][t] /. solution, tInit < t < tFin}, t]
```

And then minimizing

```
NMinimize[{x0[c1, c2][tFin] /. solution, f[c1, c2] >= -1, 
    3.5 <= c1 <= 4 && -1.5 <= c2 <= -1}, {c1, c2}]

(* {0.892063, {c1 -> 3.91284, c2 -> -1.29659}} *)
```

and the corresponding variables are

```
Through[{x1, x2, x0}[c1, c2]] /. Last[%] /. solution;
Through[%[t]];
Plot[%, {t, tInit, tFin}, AxesLabel -> {t, "x1,x2,x0"}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

This computation requires, about 15 minutes.  A faster but approximate approach is to plot `f[c1, c2]` and `x0[c1, c2][tFin] /. solution`.

```
Show[
    ContourPlot[x0[c1, c2][tFin] /. solution, {c1, 3.5, 4}, {c2, -1.5, -1}, 
        FrameLabel -> {c1, c2}],
    ContourPlot[f[c1, c2] == -1, {c1, 3.5, 4}, {c2, -1.5, -1}, 
        ContourStyle -> {Black, Thick}], 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

We see that the `f = -1` line falls furthest below the contour `0.9` neac `{3.9, -1.3}`.  A good approximation can be obtained by evaluating `x0[c1, c2][tFin] /. solution` along the `f = -1` line and then finding its minimum value there.

```
f0 = ContourPlot[f[c1, c2] == -1, {c1, 3.5, 4}, {c2, -1.5, -1}];
pts = Cases[Normal[f0], Line[z_] -> z, Infinity] // First;
val = Through[(x0 @@@ pts /. solution)[tFin]];
Ordering[val, 1] // First;
{val[[%]], pts[[%]]}

(* {0.892076, {3.91095, -1.29464}} *)
```

**Addendum: Largely Symbolic Solution**

The ODEs in the question also can be solved symbolically.  For `x1[t]`,

```
s = Collect[DSolveValue[{x1'[t] == x2[t], 
    x2'[t] == c1*E^(-t^2/paramD)/Sqrt[π*paramD] + 
    c2*E^(-(t - 1)^2/paramD)/Sqrt[π*paramD], x1[tInit] == -1/2, 
    x2[tInit] == -1}, x1[t], {t, tInit, tFin}], {c1, c2}, Simplify]

(* -(1/2) - t + c2 (E^(-(1/2) (-1 + t)^2)/Sqrt[2 π] - 1/Sqrt[2 E π] 
   - 1/2 Erf[1/Sqrt[2]] + 1/2 t Erf[1/Sqrt[2]] 
   + 1/2 (-1 + t) Erf[(-1 + t)/Sqrt[2]]) 
   + c1 ((-1 + E^(-(t^2/2)))/Sqrt[2 π] + 1/2 t Erf[t/Sqrt[2]]) *)
```

The corresponding function `g`, similar to `f` defined above, is

```
g[c1t_?NumericQ, c2t_?NumericQ] := 
    NMinValue[{s /. {c1 -> c1t, c2 -> c2t}, tInit < t < tFin}, t]
```

and the objective function is

```
i = Integrate[(c1*E^(-t^2/paramD)/Sqrt[π*paramD] + 
    c2*E^(-(t - 1)^2/paramD)/Sqrt[π*paramD])^2, {t, tInit, tFin}]

(* (2 c2^2 Erf[1] + (2 c1 c2 (Erf[1/2] + Erf[3/2]))/E^(1/4) 
   + c1^2 Erf[2])/(4 Sqrt[π]) *)
```

From these quantities, optimal values are obtained from

```
NMinimize[{i, g[c1, c2] >= -1, 3.5 <= c1 <= 4, -1.5 <= c2 <= -1}, {c1, c2}]

(* {0.892063, {c1 -> 3.91284, c2 -> -1.2966}} *)
```

in about 15 minutes.  If decimal instead of exact expressions are used in the computation,

```
{sN, iN} = {s, i} // N
```

the same results are obtained in 8 minutes.

Comment: Thank you; your answer has indicated some rather interesting directions to me.

Comment: My sincere thanks once again for the addendum.